# .. called for hands to be kept off

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Is the following sentence grammatically correct? And what does the first part exactly mean?

'SIRE (company which made the video) called for hands to be kept off our social workers, so this video must be aimed at individuals who use violence against the people that are always ready to help us.'

Comment: Do you mean _their_ social workers? Do the social workers work for SIRE? Whose social workers are they?

Comment: It's a company which creates videos that give you moral lessons. This video shows an attack on Dutch social workers and tells: 'Hands off our social workers'.

Comment: So our social workers= the Dutch social workers